# Paired android device through wifi using adb command but it does not displayed in chrome:\\inspect\#devices list

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to inspect my web app in android device, so I tried to pair device through wifi debugging using adb command. It was connected successfully again I tried to view the device using chrome dev tools(chrome://inspect/#devices) but the device not displayed in chrome dev tool. I think the network restriction happen in my laptop. Please assist anyone resolve this issue.